# Could you explain the tense usage used in this sentence "The meeting is scheduled for Friday afternoon"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In [this dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/schedule_2), it clearly says the following:

> to **schedule**: [usually passive] to arrange for something to happen
>   at a particular time
>
> **schedule something (for something)**
>
> *The meeting is scheduled for Friday afternoon.*
>
> *One of the scheduled events is a talk on alternative medicine.*
>
> *We'll be stopping here for longer than scheduled.*
>
> **schedule somebody/something to do something**
>
> *I'm scheduled to arrive in LA at 5 o'clock.*

We all know that simple present tense shows Routine Actions such as a habit, a hobby, a daily event, a scheduled event or something that often happens ([Source](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html))

Eg: *I schedule the company's meetings* (a routine action, maybe happen regularly every month)

Now, its passive form: *The company's meetings are scheduled (by me)* (a routine action)

Come back to the sentence "**The meeting is scheduled for Friday afternoon**".

Now change that passive voice to active form: "**Someone schedules the meeting for Friday afternoon**". This sentence does not make sense because simple present tense is normally for regular events.

But ["scheduled"](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=define%3Ascheduled&oq=define%3Ascheduled&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.3719j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is also an adjective. 
We can say "*a scheduled meeting*".

So, "**scheduled**" could be an adjective in "**The meeting is scheduled for Friday afternoon**".

But the dictionary clearly says "**schedule**" in "**The meeting is scheduled for Friday afternoon**" is a passive verb.

*Could you explain the tense usage used in this sentence "**The meeting is scheduled for Friday afternoon**"*?

Comment: I think "the dictionary" is wrong: _scheduled_ is an adjective here, for all the reasons you state. (Dictionaries do not usually give grammatical analysis, so I'm puzzled about how "the dictionary clearly says")

Comment: Don't you mean to say "in **a** dictionary" or *this* dictionary, @Tom?  *The dictionary* is idiomatic, it is true, but not under the circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple present is used not only with routine  actions. It can be used to state a present fact, state, or condition.

> I **take** the bus to work.  <sub>routine</sub>
>
> My shoes **are** wet from the rain.  <sub>present fact</sub>
>
> My new shoes are shiny.

Now, transitive verb **to schedule** in simple past:

> We **scheduled** the meeting <sub>direct object</sub> for next
>   Tuesday.

Now, recast in the passive:

> The meeting **was scheduled** (by us) for next Tuesday.

Now, the  past participle recast as predicate adjective to express the idea of the meeting's present state (the meeting is on the calendar):

> The meeting **is scheduled** for next Tuesday.

P.S. You can use the transitive verb in a passive construction with present-tense **is** to express a routine or recurrent scheduling:

> The meeting **is scheduled** (by the office manager) for Tuesday *afternoons*.

Comment: Let say today is Wednesday & the meeting starts at 2pm next Tuesday (ie, in 7 days). A HR staff did create this schedule yesterday. Then, today can we say "*The meeting was scheduled for next Tuesday.*"?. We can say "*The  HR staff scheduled the meeting for next Tuesday*". A person told me that I am not allowed to use simple past "*The meeting was scheduled for next Tuesday.*" because he said it would be rescheduled.

Comment: What do you mean by "would be rescheduled"? Had been rescheduled?  You can say *The meeting was scheduled for next Tuesday* and that could mean, at some point in the past the meeting was put on the calendar. You could also say *The meeting has been scheduled for next Tuesday*, and thereby mean "at some point in the past, the meeting was put on the calendar" (and that you believe the day of the meeting has not been changed in the interim). That the present perfect reaffirms the day of the meeting is not grounds for concluding that the simple past implies the day has been changed in the interim.